# How can I check at runtime if a rails app is running in the context of a sidekiq worker?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

I would like to run some code in a rails initializer only for sidekiq. Is there a way to check if my rails app is being run in the context of sidekiq? I know one way is to simply invoke it with `SIDEKIQ=yes ...` and then check for `ENV['SIDEKIQ']`, but maybe there's a more elegant way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to run a code block in an initializer, the idiomatic way is:

```
Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
  # do it
end
```

If you look at that method implementation, it's about as clear as can be:

```
yield self if server?
```

https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/blob/3330df0ee37cfd3e0cd3ef01e3e66b584b99d488/lib/sidekiq.rb#L75

Answer (score 5):

The answer, from the sidekiq creator in a comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69110578) is... *drumroll*

```
Sidekiq.server?
```