# Is there a way to log which jobs are being worked on when sidekiq is sent SIGTERM?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

When my sidekiq worker runs out of memory, I don't know what it was working on which caused this. Is there a way to log this? (other than obvious solutions like logging when starting each job).

One idea I have is to catch SIGTERM, something like this:

```
Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
  signals = %w[INT TERM]
  signals.each do |signal|
    old_handler = Signal.trap(signal) do
  
      info = []
      workers = Sidekiq::Workers.new
      workers.each do |_process_id, _thread_id, worker|
        info << work
      end
      ## -> Do something with info <- ##
          ## StatsTracker.count("#{job.name} being processed when shutdown")
  
      if old_handler.respond_to?(:call)
        old_handler.call
      else
        exit
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: `Sidekiq.server?`

Comment: @MikePerham Thanks! I added that as the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69110567). Any ideas for tracking which jobs were running when the server died?